# Hardware interface for floating joint

Tags: ros-control, hardware-interface, ros-foxy

In the URDF file for my robot I would like to use a floating joint (6DOF). I'm currently writing the hardware interface for ros2-control for this robot. Is there a way to export a state interface for a floating joint, or do I have to use a series of 3 revolute and 3 prismatic joints?

So ideally i was looking for something like this:

```
state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(6dof_joint.name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION, &6dof_joint.pos));
```

Where `6dof_joint.pos` would be a 6D vector or transformation matrix. But as far as I've seen `Hardware_interface::StateInterface` only accepts (1D) `double*` so I guess floating joint is not supported?

Comment: FWIW, [hardware_interface::StateInterface Class Reference](https://control.ros.org/galactic/doc/api/classhardware__interface_1_1StateInterface.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, one can use only a scalar double value per hardware interface. But this is only data storage location, so you have to export six interfaces and your floating joint is "supported".

Using joint_state_broadcaster/robot_state_publisher combination or gazebo_ros2_control, you'll need explicit serial 1-dof joints anyhow, see e.g. [here](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/blob/9a50d7897d6437a63af1d9f8e602240105b35b2d/src/robot_state_publisher.cpp#L227-L229).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear (at least the first paragraph). Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers help center.